# jQuery Mobile panel smooth scrolling

Tags: jquery-mobile, animation, scroll, panel, smooth-scrolling

This is not a question about JQM panels scrolling independently of the page, though that is an issue I've had trouble with and almost overcome, this is about making the panel scroll smoothly and ignore the device browser's edge event (or whatever the correct term is, I'll explain below).

Basically, I'm trying to replicate the menu on Google's mobile site, which naturally isn't using JQM like us common folk. I've got it pretty close, but the scrolling animation is very rigid. I need it be momentum-based rather than fixed to your finger.

Also, when you reach the top or bottom of the menu, it's considered the extremes of the document so the browser moves the whole document up or down to indicate the edge of the page. Instead, the page should never move while the panel is open and the menu should take on this behaviour within the panel.

Since I've set the panel height to 100%, this forces the address bar on iOS Safari to come down when the menu is open. This seems to be exactly what happens on Google, but if there's a way around this I'd love to hear it.

Finally, one downside of the way I've emulated independent scrolling is to just set the content wrap as fixed when the panel is open. However, this means the page always scrolls to the top when the panel opens. Any alternatives for this would be appreciated. I suppose I could just set the page top as scrollTop or something.

To summarise:

- Panel menu needs to scroll smoothly (momentum rather than direct touch)
- Elastic edge on menu rather than window
- iOS Safari address bar interfering with height
- Page fixed at top when panel open

If any of my descriptions don't make sense, just visit google.com on your phone and check out their menu.

Answer (score 1):

[ScrollFix](https://github.com/joelambert/ScrollFix) seems to have solved all my issues.